# Formatting or beautifying javascript in SublimeText

Tags: formatting, sublime-text-2

The thread " *[Is there an HTML auto-indentation feature or plugin for Sublime Text (aka prettify/beautify/format)?](https://superuser.com/questions/564180/is-there-an-html-auto-indentation-feature-or-plugin-for-sublime-text-aka-pretti)* " refers to an HTML formatter for SublimeText.
Does anyone know of something equivalent for javascript?

At the very least it needs to:

- fix indentation
- remove extra white spaces
- remove extra blank lines

Answer (score 2):

If you install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and then use its [search function](https://sublime.wbond.net/search) you can find plugins for just about anything.

In this case, I'd recommend using [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify). Make sure you have node.js installed **and in your path**, and make sure you read through the setup instructions carefully to get everything up and running. Other options include [JSFormat](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JsFormat), which doesn't require node, and [JavaScript Beautify](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Javascript%20Beautify), which uses the same library as JSFormat but for some reason requires you to install it yourself.